# How to add a stubMapping to a Wiremock server in Version 2.1.7?

Tags: java, rest, junit, wiremock

The new version 2.1.7 of Wiremock changed a lot. Some of the previous methods seems not to be available anymore for a direct approach by adding stubs programmatically during runtime.

For example I could add a stub in version 1.57 like this:

```
private void setStub(WireMockServer server, String url, RequestMethod requestMethod, Object body)
throws JsonProcessingException {

    UrlMatchingStrategy urlStrategy = new UrlMatchingStrategy();
    urlStrategy.setUrl(url);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

    StubMapping mapping = new MappingBuilder(requestMethod, urlStrategy).willReturn(
   new ResponseDefinitionBuilder().withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").withBody(jsonInString)).build();

    server.addStubMapping(mapping);
}
```

How can I accomplish that for 2.1.7? 
(Yes I read the documentation, but I found only JUnit annotations, which in my case are not useful).

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I finally figured out how to write the same method for the version 2.1.7:

```
private void setStub(WireMockServer server, String url, RequestMethod requestMethod, Object body)
     throws JsonProcessingException {

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(body);

  server.addStubMapping(
        WireMock.request(requestMethod.getName(), WireMock.urlMatching(url))
              .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse().withStatus(200).withBody(jsonInString)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain").withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    )
              .build());
}
```

Comment: Use static imports instead of saying `WireMock.aResponse()`, etc. To do that, change the code to `aResponse()` and then when importing, do a static import. It shortens the code a lot making it more readable.

Comment: I need a "standalone" version, not a Junit Test. Therefore using static imports are of no use in this case.